# Trouble with jar file and image

Tags: java, image, jar

I have coded a program in Eclipse and it works properly when I run in that.

```
public static void initialize() throws IOException{     

    JTextField tfQrText;
    int size = 250;
    File qrFile;
    BufferedImage qrBufferedImage;

    JFrame gui = new JFrame("qrCode Generator");
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setSize(250, 340);
    gui.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    gui.setResizable(false);


    File iconFile = new File(VisualQrCodeGenerator.class.getResource("icon.png").getFile());    
    BufferedImage iconBuffered = ImageIO.read(iconFile);
    gui.setIconImage(iconBuffered);

    JButton generate = new JButton("Generate qrCode");
    gui.add(generate,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    tfQrText = new JTextField();
    PromptSupport.setPrompt("Enter Your Text ... ", tfQrText);
    gui.add(tfQrText,BorderLayout.NORTH);


    qrFile = new File(VisualQrCodeGenerator.class.getResource("qrCodeImage.png").getFile());
    qrBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(qrFile);
    ImageIcon qrImageIcon = new ImageIcon(qrBufferedImage);

    JLabel image = new JLabel();
    image.setIcon(qrImageIcon);

    image.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

    gui.add(image,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    gui.setVisible(true);
    generate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(!(tfQrText.getText().equals(""))){
                //create() Method make the QRcode Image
                create();
            }               
        }
    });
```

The Error occurs on line:

```
BufferedImage iconBuffered = ImageIO.read(iconFile);
```

When I make it `.jar` file, it says:
[image: Opening file with windows CMD to know why it won't open]

My Project structure is like this:

```
+src
+qrCodeGenerator
  -VisualQrCodeGenerator
  -icon.png
  -qrCodeImage.png
```

The code is running properly and without any error in program and I can work with it. But when I make it .jar file, it errors me as I uploaded it image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal: you can't access a classpath resource as a `File` object. This is because it is embedded inside a JAR. It works inside your IDE because resources are typically stored inside a temporary folder (and not inside a JAR).

You need to access it with an `InputStream` using [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) and use [`ImageIO.read(InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.InputStream-) instead.

As such, change your code to:

```
qrBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(VisualQrCodeGenerator.class.getResourceAsStream("qrCodeImage.png"));
```

and

```
iconBuffered = ImageIO.read(VisualQrCodeGenerator.class.getResourceAsStream("icon.png"));
```

Comment: While this is true, you'll get an NPE if the resource does not exist. The best way is to first `.getResource()`, check that the result is not null, then `.openStream()` that resource (which is a `URL` object).

Comment: @fge Yes, but having a NPE if the resource doesn't exist also enables to fail fast.

Comment: Sure, but you can then detect that and throw a better exception instead ;)